# Retornar a quantidade de elementos repetidos em uma lista

Tags: python, lista

Bom dia pessoal, poderia me ajudar em uma dúvida?
Como eu faço para retornar a quantidade de elementos que se repetem em uma lista no python?
Por exemplo:
Uma lista=[4,2,1,6,1,4,4] deve retornar os valor 2, pois há dois elementos que se repetem na lista.
Alguém pode me ajudar como fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso de forma nativa montando um `set()` com todos os elementos que se repetem, e contando a quantidade de elementos nesse `set` usando `len()`:

```
lista = [ 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 4, 4 ]

qtd = len( set( [ item for item in lista if lista.count( item ) > 1] ) )

print( qtd )
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma é utilizar a estrutura `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

lista = [4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 4, 4]
contador = Counter(lista)

repetidos = [
    item for item, quantidade in contador.items() 
        if quantidade > 1
]

quantidade_repetidos = len(repetidos)

print(f'Há {quantidade_repetidos} números repetidos na lista')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/DeadMealyTruetype) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Nzt3ne) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/da49e152a38828906628ef357c23ffd9)</sup>

A saída será:

```
Há 2 números repetidos na lista
```

O `Counter` basicamente define um dicionário onde a chave serão os valores da lista e o respectivo valor a quantidade de vezes que apareceu na lista original; assim, basta filtrar os elementos que possuem quantidade maior que 1.

Answer (score 0):

Em uma função fica ótimo!

```
from collections import Counter


def remove_dups(l1, l2):
    for x in l1:
        l2.append(x)
        if Counter(l1)[x] == 1:
            l1.remove(x)


l1 = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3]
l2 = []


remove_dups(l1)

print('Removed numbers ' + str(l1))
print(l2)
```

Comment: Mas desta forma você irá criar uma nova instância de `Counter` a cada iteração; e irá modificar a lista de entrada, o que não é uma boa ideia, pois pode gerar efeitos colaterais.